# JPA failed to persist record with ManyToOne foreign key association

Tags: jpa, entitymanager, persist

What is the difference between EntityManager.find() method and a customized query to select that particular data entry?

I have a Student entity which has a foreign key constraint to the School entity via SCHOOL_ID. When persisting a new student record, JPA attempts to insert an existing school entry to the SCHOOL table, which results in DB integrity exceptions. The school entry was added to the student record by below code:

```
student.setSchool(em.createNamedQuery("getSchoolByName", School.class).setParameter("name", schoolName).getSingleResult());
```

The query is

```
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="getSchoolByName", query="SELECT sc FROM School sc WHERE ts.name = :name")})
```

There is a unique constraint on the school name field, hence a given name will yield single result for sure.

But if I use the find() method to retrieve the school record via its id (primary key), there is no such problem.

```
student.setSchool(em.find(School.class, schoolId));
```

Both STUDENT and SCHOOL table take id as their primary key.

The foreign key association in the Student entity class looks like

```
//uni-directional many-to-one association to TestSuite
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=School.class,cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name="SCHOOL_ID", referencedColumnName="SCHOOL_ID", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
private School school;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a persistence context problem. The query was actually made by a new entity manager which has a different context from the entity manager that handles the persist. Once unified into one entity manager, there was no more issue. find() and the customized query yield the same result.